# Is there a good way to combine the incremental behavior of rdiff-backup with the inotify behavior of lsyncd?

Tags: backup, rdiff-backup, inotify, lsyncd

I'm trying to backup a directory (my Zotero data, in particular) whenever it changes (a la syncing with drop box); I would also like to keep a history of backups in case I delete something and want to restore it. `lsyncd` solves the first of these; `rdiff-backup` solves the second, but I can find no good way to combine these. The closest thing I can come up with is to run `lsyncd` locally and `rdiff-backup` remotely.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Watchman](https://github.com/facebook/watchman). It's a tool created by Facebook for the purposes of watching file changes and triggering an action. Have it trigger a script which records what files changed before triggering an rsync.